# get_the_term_list give me a whitespace

Tags: php, terms

I'm using this code to get my term list, It works fine, but it also give me a white space before my TERM name,
Any thoughts?

```
<span class="metaorange"><?php $terms_as_text = strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $wp_query->post->ID,'genre','',',',''));
echo $terms_as_text; ?></span>
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the output?

Comment: Can you verify this has nothing to do with the `strip_tags`?

Comment: Any progress on this question?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you got any [`term_links-genre` filters](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/category-template.php#L1303) that could be modifying your `get_the_term_list()` output?

Your code example should in general work as expected, but you might want to use the `get_the_terms()` function to better control the output to your own likings.

Here's a modifed version of the corresponding [Codex example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms#A_Basic_Example):

```
/**
 * Customized the term list
 *
 * @param  int    $pid
 * @param  string $tax
 * @param  string $seperator
 * @return string $out
 */

function custom_the_term_list( $pid = 0, $tax = 'category', $seperator = ',' )
{
    $out = '';
    $terms = get_the_terms( $pid, $tax );
    if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
        $list = array();
        foreach ( $terms as $term )    
        {
            $list[] = $term->name;
        }
        $out = join( $seperator, $list );
    endif;
    return $out;
}
```

Usage example:

```
printf( '<span class="metaorange">%s</span>',
    custom_the_term_list( get_the_id(), 'genre', ',' )
);
```